# AS3 annoying issue with png as a cursor - stopDrag and startDrag

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, png

I've never run into this problem in the past, but when I use a `png` as my default `cursor` in an application i'm developing, it stops working with the `startDrag` and `stopDrag`.

When before I import the png of the simple vector graphic (a scribble) it works fine.

Do the alpha channels throw the code out?

If so, is there a work around that still allow me to use the `png` in this way?

It's a `png` of some tweezers with dropshadow.

```
// ------------------------ tweeze tool
 Mouse.hide();
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);
  function follow(evt:MouseEvent){
    tweezed_one.x = mouseX;
    tweezed_one.y = mouseY;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear.

But what I understood is that you are not aware of `mouseChildren` while using custom cursor.

Add this line where you created it,

```
tweezed_one.mouseChildren = false;
```

Now you will be able to drag and drop.

For more info see [`mouseChildren`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren)

Comment: Interesting, thank you. It's quite odd little issue that I ran into, I never came across it before and it could be more graphical format issue opposed to a coding one.  May I ask what mouseChildren does?

Comment: `mouseChildren` refers to children of target (i.e custom cursor).